# Problems with a simple while loop

Tags: c++, loops, vector, while-loop

I'm on the "looping while" segment of a book named c++ programming written by Mike McGrath.

In the book it explains how a while loop works and what it can and cannot do etc. It gives an example code which I understand for the most part except for something that the book does not explain and I was wondering if any of you could explain it.

This is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std ;

int main(){

 vector <int> vec(10) ;
 int i = 0 ;


  while (i < vec.size()){
    i ++ ; 
    vec[i-1] = i ;
    cout << " | " << vec.at(i-1) ;
  }
}
```

Now, this is the way I am reading this, and I'm sure I'm reading it the wrong way because the results make no sense to me:

While i is less than 10 (vector's size) continue executing this code. So integer i is 0, but it increments to 1 at the beginning of the code. Next however, is the part I am so confused about.

It says vec[i-1], why is he subtracting 1? And then making it equal to i? If I try to make it `vec[i] = i;` the program crashes. So the way I am reading it is, `vec[i - 0 ]` would have to be 0 since 0 was just incremented to 1 on the previous step of the while loop. Then to display the results he once again calls the command `vec.at()` to i-1, which further confuses me. I simply do not understand what the -1 means within the vector. Shouldn't what's inside the brackets mean the position within the vector?

[image: The code]

[image: The execution]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Lightness has pointed out, he need to substract 1 to get back to 0 based indexing.  The loop is same as below.

```
vector<int> vec(10);
int i = 0;
while(i < vec.size())
{
    vec[i] = i + 1;
    cout << " |" << vec.at(i);
    i++;
}
```

- that's why the output printed 1 to 10.
- within the vector, [i-1] means minus current value of i by 1 then assign the value as index to vector. (note: the substracted value is not assigned back to i)
- same description as above for vec.at(i-1)

Comment: And this is a much better way of writing it.  (Of course, you probably shouldn't be using `at`, but rather `[]`, with debugging options turned on.  But it doesn't matter here.)

Answer (score 7):

Because in the first line of the loop body he's incremented `i` (making it `1` on the first iteration), so he needed to subtract 1 to get back to valid array indexing (whereby `0` is the first index of an array, and `n-1` is the last).

The program crashes when you change that, because you'd be accessing `vec[1]` to `vec[N]` (where `N` is the vector size) instead of `vec[0]` to `vec[N-1]`, the real valid range of the vector.

He's assigning `i` so that each vector element contains an incrementing count. It's a bit confusing.

```
vec[0] = 1
vec[1] = 2
vec[2] = 3
...
vec[9] = 10
```

It would be better written like this:

```
int i = 0;
while (i < vec.size()) {
   vec[i] = i+1;
   cout << " | " << vec[i];
   i++;
}
```

or:

```
for (int i = 0; i < vec.size(); i++) {
   vec[i] = i+1;
   cout << " | " << vec[i];
}
```

Comment: I assume that not the operator[] "crashes" the program, since most of the times the reserved memory is more than the size, but at() will definitely raise an uncaught exception and thus abort the program

Comment: I'm beginning to understand it, what's inside of the bracket signifies the position, and the rest is simply what will print out on the screen, that is why the subtracting or adding is necessary.